# VB.Net Picture with Background Saving

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010

I need to save the PictureBox including its background to JPG file in the hard drive;
So far I can load the picture from Resources, then save the PictureBox to the Hard drive, but it deletes the background;
My code is below:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("test.jpg")
    Dim Image As New Bitmap(800, 400)
    Dim MekSaveImage As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image)
    For Parts = 0 To 3
        RRRR = 10 + Parts * 198
        Dim RectPen As New Pen(Color.Red)
        RectPen.Width = 2
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(RRRR, 10, 188, 300)
        MekSaveImage.DrawRectangle(RectPen, rect)
    Next
    PictureBox1.Image = Image
    PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Test\Test.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for help/comment.

Comment: Draw the `.BackgroundImage` of the picturebox to your `Image` using the `MekSaveImage` object as well before the loop.

Comment: Thanks Jens for the comments; probably 2 lines of code required; can you please tell me the code... I am trying but seems I am doing some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you have your Backgroundimage in the `test.jpg` and want to draw the rectangles on top.

Start off with the image. The Ressource itself is not altered.

```
Dim BackgroundImage As Bitmap = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("test.jpg")
```

Create a graphics object from this image and draw the rectangles on top. You don't need to create a graphics image from a new image. You can use exisiting ones that will then be used as a canvas.

```
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BackgroundImage)
    'Draw the Rectangles
    Using RectPen As New Pen(Color.Red)
        RectPen.Width = 2
        For Parts = 0 To 3
            RRRR = 10 + Parts * 198
            Dim rect As New Rectangle(RRRR, 10, 188, 300)
            g.DrawRectangle(RectPen, rect)
        Next
    End Using 'RectPen
End Using 'g
PictureBox1.Image = BackgroundImage  'Display the result
BackgroundImage.Save("C:\Test\Test.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 'Save to disk.
```

I am using `Using` blocks to make sure to dispose ressources of the graphics object and the pen.